# Asking for good ASP.NET MVC 6 documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to learn Asp.net MVC6 for developing web Applications , I don't have any knowledge about it and i'm looking for a book,tutorial for absolute beginner and which there is evey detail about Asp.net MVC(I like details )

Thank you

Comment: AspNet Mvc 6 was renamed to aspnet core 1.0

Comment: Well, it's in fact "ASP.NET Core MVC" to be precise :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/) is very good with examples and explanation on how to do things.

I have read it while it was still ASP.NET vNext in beta and it was already good with just few interesting things missing. Now it should cover pretty much everything.

I would recommend the [.NET Core fundamentals](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/index.html) as well, maybe even start with it, but it depends on how you like to study.

Answer (score -1):

Scott Allen has really great tutorial videos.
You can check some of those out [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals).

Anyways, I started out by watching about 16 hours worth of his videos.

Edit: This link I provided points to MVC5 videos, although I still believe to be useful when learning how to develop asp.net applications.

Comment: He's asking for aspnet mvc 6 (which is now aspnet core), not aspnet mvc 5